# Subtracting from a variable in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have to make the variable $tmp2 to equal $len - 15
I have not found anything that says how to simply subtract in NSIS

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`IntOp` instruction](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#intop) to perform basic 32-bit math operations:

```
IntOp $temp2 $len - 15
MessageBox MB_OK "Result is $temp2"
```